# How can I create a crowdsale for tokens already held in my wallet?

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, tokens, ico, crowdsale

For example, I had an initial crowdsale with a specific end date. The end date passed and then the unsold tokens were forwarded to my wallet address.

How can a new crowdsale contract be created for these tokens? Is it possible for some kind of contract to be deployed where I send these tokens to it and it progresses with the crowdsale contract as the owner of the tokens who sells them (as my initial crowdsale contract does)?

Thanks in advance, I appreciate any help.

Comment: Yes. Was there some specific part of that you're having trouble with? My code in https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2018/02/02/writing-a-token-sale-contract/ works that way.

Comment: Cross-linking with https://www.reddit.com/r/ethdev/comments/8i6c7i/how_can_i_create_a_crowdsale_for_tokens_already/?st=jgz72n92&sh=f53b4a00.

Comment: Thanks. In your example you use IERC20Token public tokenContract; for the token being sold. How would this work when 100% of the total supply of the token is either owned by previous purchasers or in my wallet that I forwarded them to after the initial crowdsale?

Comment: I don't think I understand the question. If you have the tokens, you can transfer them to the new crowdsale contract.

Comment: Ah, ok. So I could deploy the new Crowdsale contract, Then simply transfer my tokens to the new crowdsale address and that would update the crowdsale balance and it could proceed as with a regular crowdsale?

Comment: That's the basic idea. In the code I shared, that's the only way the crowdsale works. Without seeing your code, I have no idea what it does.

Comment: Thanks. This is the layout of my code at the moment if you want to critique it or understand where I am coming from. https://pastebin.com/raw/BiJ7SS8n 

Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Your crowdsale contract creates a new token, so that won't work to sell an existing token.

Comment: Yes, my apologies for being unclear. My question is relating to once this crowdsale ends I want to be able to have another crowdsale using those created tokens. Thanks so much.

Comment: you can have another crowd sale afterwards, just create a new contract and send the erc20 funds to it. Smarx reference is perfect for your scenario.